# Ubuntu Software error message: Checksum failure

Tags: snap, 21.04

### Summary

Everything goes on well except 'Update' in Ubuntu Software:

> Unable to get list of updates: Failed to update metadata for lvfs:
> checksum failure: failed to verify data, expected
> ab367e987025d2339a62fb40a400149f7dc7dc7def5

### Process

Since yesterday, I cannot use the 'update' function in Ubuntu Software anymore, I don't know the exact reason.

### Current and expected result

I remember that there are 4 software still waiting for update yesterday, but they disappeared and the update module in Ubuntu Software is broken, I wish it can work well like before.

Comment: I'm facing this error message as well (Discover 5.18.5 on Kubuntu 20.04.3), but it doesn't prevent me from installing package updates though.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Open terminal and try this command

```
fwupdmgr --force refresh
```

From [man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man1/fwupdmgr.1.html):

> `--force`
> Force the action by relaxing some runtime checks
>
> `refresh [FILE FILE_SIG REMOTE-ID]`
> Refresh metadata from remote server

Comment: That may or may not fix it. As of 2021-10-12, there's an [open bug](https://github.com/fwupd/fwupd/issues/3652) and they're still trying to pin down the root cause.

Comment: Worked fine with Debian 11.

Comment: The real answer is in @ssokolow s comment: this is a known bug in fwupd. According to the bug comments, the forced refresh workaround is only temporary, the error message will return in 24 hours. Ubuntu bug report on Launchpad: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libjcat/+bug/1943833

Comment: @AttilaCsipak cronjob you say...